# Quickblox Android SDK- how to extract remote video/audio and stream various local sources?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Official quickblox  documentation is very limited in any details for working with local/remote  media streams. I could not find any example /documentation on :

1. how to extract remote media stream  from the session in order to work with the streamed remote video and audio tracks. I would like to extract the video/frames and audio from the session (the opponent remote stream) to further process (save image, or record the stream data)
2. how to change the source for the local stream from mic/camera to e.g. a stored video or various streams. I would like to send for example  a pre-recorder message or video in case of busy opponent.

Any idea, if it can be done by extending any of the Quickblox libraries/classes, as it seems there is no public built in direct method or support for working with the streams?

[The official doc for the WebRtc video calls](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android)

Comment: are you able to implement this? let me know I am also in need of similar functionality in quickblox@Majo

Comment: Not really. I have given up with Quickblox from many reasons, one of them being the functionality.  I have not tested the latest version if they progressed on the issue. Last time (a year ago or so )  I raised a ticket for the missing functionality which was closed with an answer it was in pipeline... Moreover I was disappointed  with the lag in the libraries (both webRTC and push messages, and the fact they changed the library usage every quarter which was annoying to re do my work everytime I upgraded to the latest versions. Nor saying the incomplete or poor documentation

Comment: But if you checked their latest version they say it is possible to capture video stream and screen: But again the documentation is poor here on how. You can test and let us know if you succeeded. Audio seems not yet supported: [link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Set_video_capturer)